# Searching all sheets in a workbook, return address of each instance

Tags: vba, excel, find

First of all, I am very new to VBA and have a very very basic understanding of coding in general. Also, I have researched this and tried several different methods before asking this because I am too prideful to admit that I can’t figure something out most of the time. But this one has stumped me and I can’t afford to spend anymore time on it.

I’m working with a workbook that was created and managed by someone else. It is very unorganized and has thousands of rows in each sheet. I originally wanted to create a way that I could use this workbook in a more efficient way. Now, my boss wants me to make it work for everyone else in my department as well. This has added the need for a way to show the location of each instance.

I am writing all of this from my phone because my company keeps everything locked down and if I tried to post anything I was working on, I’m sure I’d be fired.

I would like for it to take the input from the prompt, search and then just list every instance  of it in the form of “Sheet Name, Address” if possible.

This is the original code that I wrote just to get something to work quickly for my needs. I doubt I can or should use any of it going forward but this gives a good idea of what I’m working with. I used If functions to go through each page because I knew I could get that to work and it would be mostly idiot proof.

```
Sub Searcher

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Prompt As String
Dim RetValue As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RowCrnt As Long

Do While True
   RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & “Enter info to search for”)
      If RetValue = “” Then
         Exit Do
      End If

      With Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Activate
         Set Rng = Cells.Find(RetValue)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
               RowCrnt = Rng.Row
               Rng.Activate
               Prompt = “I found this info in Sheet1 in row “”” & RowCrnt & “”””
            Else
               With Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Activate
                   ‘ Same thing again for each sheet in the workbook
                   Else
                        Prompt = “This information does not exist in this workbook”
                End With
              End If
       End With
    Prompt = Prompt & vbLf
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to perform a different search upon each sheet. The following allows you to perform 1 search, across all sheets and outputs a `MsgBox` to let you know what it found.

```
Sub Searcher()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim RetValue As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RowCrnt As Long

    RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & "Enter info to search for")
    If RetValue = "" Then
       Exit Sub
    End If


    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

       Set Rng = Sh.Cells.Find(RetValue)
          If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
             RowCrnt = Rng.Row
             Prompt = Prompt & "I found this info in " & sh.Name & " in row """ & RowCrnt & """" & vbLf
          End If
     Next

    If Prompt = "" Then Prompt = "Nothing found"

    MsgBox Prompt

End Sub
```

Comment: I’m still not sure why your code can add the results as a list when I version of mine that was like this couldn’t. But either way, this worked. Thank you for the help!

Comment: In your version, you **re-write** `Prompt` on each find. In my version, I **append** a new `Prompt` to the existing `Prompt` and then once all is found I output it.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of these as the answer if you're happy with the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through each Worksheet in a separate Sub, and then calling the "Searcher" Sub, passing each Worksheet as a parameter.

```
Sub ForEachWorksheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Searcher(ws)
    Next
End Sub

Sub Searcher(WsToSearch)

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Prompt As String
Dim RetValue As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RowCrnt As Long

Set Sh = WsToSearch

Do While True
   RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & “Enter info to search for”)
      If RetValue = “” Then
         Exit Do
      End If

      With Sheets(Sh)
         Set Rng = Cells.Find(RetValue)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
               RowCrnt = Rng.Row
               Rng.Activate
               Prompt = “I found this info in Sheet1 in row “”” & RowCrnt & “”””
            Else
               With Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Activate
                   ‘ Same thing again for each sheet in the workbook
                   Else
                        Prompt = “This information does not exist in this workbook”
                End With
              End If
       End With
    Prompt = Prompt & vbLf
Loop

End Sub
```